# Graphing In R with multiple inputs

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I have a data set like this

```
 A B C   D 
 1 4 10  13
 1 5 10  13
 2 6 11  14
 2 7 11  14
 3 8 12  15
 3 9 12  15
```

I want to graph B on the x-axis and have both the c and d values graphed on the y axis. I want to color the y-values by the variable A. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you running into problems?